# Updating ImageIcon in JTree without repainting the Tree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, repaint, treemodel

Basically I edit an attribute `private string status="OK"` in the `UserObject()` of a `DefaultTreeNode()`.

I have a CustomRenderer which `implements DefaultCellRenderer`, which sets the Icon by rendering the "OK" attribute of `UserObject` of a `TreeNode`.

Originally, when I select a node, the icon changes. I am using `Tree.revalidate()` & `Tree.repaint()`, and the change is being reflected.

However, I am not sure if this very efficient. What would be the proper way of doing this? I tried doing `TreeModel.nodesChanged(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(myUserObject))` but the `TreeNodeChanged event` will not fire.

So am I stuck to using repainting the entire tree everytime a userboject of a TreeNode is changed to see the graphic update?

Comment: no need for revalidate/-paint if the notification is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the approach shown in [`TreeIconDemo2`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#eg) to condition the renderer based on the model's value. For example,

```
private class MyRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

    private Icon okIcon;

    public MyRenderer(Icon okIcon) {
        this.okIcon = okIcon;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
        boolean sel, boolean exp, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(
            tree, value, sel, exp, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        YourMutableTreeNode node = (YourMutableTreeNode) value;
        if (leaf && node.getStatus().equals("OK")) {
            setIcon(okIcon);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Addendum: You can't simply invoke [`nodeChanged()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#nodeChanged%28javax.swing.tree.TreeNode%29) on a  new `TreeNode` that's not part of the tree; the new node has no parent. If you specify an existing node to `nodeChanged()`, the notification will happen automatically. If needed, there's an example of searching a tree [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8210759/230513).

Comment: technically correct, just: the time it will be called "next" is accidental if change notification is missing :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you want the model to be updated, as you do here, you are correct that you want to call nodeChanged.  What I think may be wrong is that you are passing in an entirely new node, which obviously doesn't match one found in the tree.  Try passing in a reference to the node in the tree you modified - that way the model can find know which node you modified.