# Change the color of one or more nodes in Jtree dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jtree, cellrenderer, background-foreground

I have created Jtree with Root node and 4Subnodes.
My problem is like this:

- I need to
  change the foreground and background color of a particular node dynamically.

How can i do it?

Help me with some piece of code.
Thank you all in advance...

Answer (score 1):

> How can i do it?

I'm sure that [JTree tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) contains valuable info about [DefaultTreeCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display),

> Help me with some piece of code.

tons of examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Catalog0240__Swing.htm) or [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.tree/pkg.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20TreeCellRenderer)

Comment: It's the right approach; you can change the icon, too, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8351850/230513).

Answer (score 0):

One easy way I found was to include HTML markup in the node text.
The renderer (Windows 7, Java7.45) respects font color changes.
Low-rent but gets the job done!