# How to change style (color, font) of a single JTree node

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtree, renderer

I have two `JTree` in two panels in a `JFrame`. I want to change the style(color and font) of nodes on drag and drop from one tree to the other.Please provide me a way to change the color of a `JTree` node permanently.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To start, you will need to have a data object that can handle style and color. You could subclass DefaultMutableTreeNode and add these data items with getts and setters

Then you'd need to create a custom TreeCellRenderer. I recommend extending DefaultTreeCellRenderer, and in the overridden handler, checking for your custom class, and modifying the JLabel output to use the Font and Color if these values are set

Comment: No, it would be helpful if YOU provided some code. Then we could help you fix whatever was wrong with it

Comment: +1 for `TreeCellRenderer`. @soumitrachatterjee: A related example may be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8351850/230513); adding `setForeground(Color.blue)` may help you create an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: user1291492  no luck...please help me a bit....i am trying with your example...i have two DefaultMutableTreeNode  objects :DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path
          .getLastPathComponent();
      DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(element);

Comment: i want to color this parent and node object....in which method i will pass these two as argument.???Please Help...

Answer (score 9):

Create your own `CellRenderer`. To give the appropriate behaviour to your `MyTreeCellRenderer`, you will have to extend [`DefaultTreeCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellRenderer.html) and override the [`getTreeCellRendererComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellRenderer.html#getTreeCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTree,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int,%20boolean)) method.

```
public class MyTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean sel, boolean exp, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, exp, leaf, row, hasFocus);

        // Assuming you have a tree of Strings
        String node = (String) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();

        // If the node is a leaf and ends with "xxx"
        if (leaf && node.endsWith("xxx")) {
            // Paint the node in blue
            setForeground(new Color(13, 57 ,115));
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

---

Finally, say your tree is called `myTree`, set your `CellRenderer` to it:

```
myTree.setCellRenderer(new MyTreeCellRenderer());
```

Comment: This runs perfectly, great piece of code! But, what if want to change also the background color of the tree? When in the `MyTreeCellRenderer`, under the line `setForeground(new Color(13, 57 ,115));`, I write `setBackground(Color.YELLOW);`, the background of the tree does not turn to yellow..

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500414/treecellrenderer-how-to-set-background-color helps