# Finding the node where an instance belong

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtree, weka

I generated a decision tree based on a set of data, then I converted this data to a xml file, after that I put it into a JTree. This part works fine but now I have to take a new instance(which contains the data received from the user), find it's place in the decision tree and change that node's color. And I can't find a way to do that. I am using weka and the J48 classifier to generate the decision tree. The xml is created in the Luc Sorel style: http://www.lucsorel.com/media/downloads/sample_decision_tree.xml
The first thing I tried was to classify the instance using the algorithm but that gets me only the class where it belongs, and I don't know how to locate it in the JTree.
What should I do? Any ideeas?

Answer (score 2):

Like `JTable`, `JTree` uses a flyweight [renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display) to draw nodes. As the default renderer is a `JLabel`, you can set the foreground color or make the label opaque and set the background color. This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8351850/230513) changes the icon for emphasis. More examples may be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#eg).

Addendum: *I cannot find … the node that I should color.*

When `getTreeCellRendererComponent()` is called, `value` is a reference to the node to be rendered, and the `tree` parameter allows access to the `TreeModel` as a whole via `getModel()`. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8210759/230513) shows how to search a tree.

Comment: Thx, but my problem is that I cannot find the node where the instance should be. I mean finding the node that I should color.