# Dynamically change icon of specific nodes in JTree

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtree, renderer

I've seen plenty of examples for changing the icon of nodes during tree instantiation, but I'd like a way to dynamically change the icon of an individual node later.  So, in my main code I add my custom renderer to my tree:

```
// Icon I want to set nodes to later
ImageIcon checkIcon = new ImageIcon("check.jpg");

// Creates tree with my nodes
JTree tree = new JTree(nodes.top);

// Create custom renderer
Scenario1Renderer renderer = new Scenario1Renderer();

// Set to single tree selection 
tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);

// Set tree to my custom renderer
//renderer.setRendererIcon(greenIcon);
tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

My code in the renderer is

```
public class Scenario1Renderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

ImageIcon rendererIcon;

    public void setRendererIcon(ImageIcon myIcon){
      this.rendererIcon = myIcon;
    };

public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent( 
         JTree tree, 
         Object value, 
         boolean sel, 
         boolean expanded, 
         boolean leaf, 
         int row, 
         boolean hasFocus)
{ 

    Component ret = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value,
            selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
            //setIcon( rendererIcon ) ;
            return ret;
    }
```

So, obviously if I set my rendererIcon, it'll paint all my nodes with the icon I pass in during tree instantiation.  I instead want some sort of method that can set the icon of an individual node later on in the execution of my program.

Comment: there I can't see any difference, don't understand, whats reason

Comment: *"I've seen plenty of examples for changing the icon of nodes during tree instantiation, but I'd like a way to dynamically change the icon of an individual node later"*  So add that ability to the renderer. I don't see how this is special in any way.  I am surprised your research has not shown up examples of a 'dynamic' way to render the cells.  There should be a great number of e.g.s that show how to render the data differently at run-time and depending on the content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have different icons that you can set according to different conditions. Below is a simple example that changes icon of a selected node:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

public class TestTree {
    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final JTree tree = new JTree(buildDemoModel());

        tree.setCellRenderer(new DefaultTreeCellRenderer() {
            private Icon loadIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
            private Icon saveIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
            @Override
            public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree,
                    Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded,
                    boolean isLeaf, int row, boolean focused) {
                Component c = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value,
                        selected, expanded, isLeaf, row, focused);
                if (selected)
                    setIcon(loadIcon);
                else
                    setIcon(saveIcon);
                return c;
            }
        });
        tree.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(tree));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static DefaultTreeModel buildDemoModel() {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");

        root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("A"));
        root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("B"));
        root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("C"));

        return new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: For reference, a similar approach is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14097270/230513).

Comment: Also note that `((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject()` yields an Object you can cast to the original item you placed into the tree.

Comment: for reference, `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` will change the node's selection background and foreground color ,when you click any node the node not show gray highlight , this issue you can use `this.selected = selected;
   this.hasFocus = hasFocus;` to fix it . Hope this helps others.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to target individual handles when the mouse is over them? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40887102/add-rollover-to-jtree-handles)

Comment: @Dan I don't think TreeUI supports this out of the box. if it worth the trouble you'd have to extend TreeUI. Take a look at `BasicTreeUI.paintExpandControl()`.

Comment: @tenorsax Thank you. I will look into this

Comment: @tenorsax Thanks again. I now have a solution working off what you said. If you interested see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40943405/4601149)