# How to set custom icons for individual nodes on a JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtree

I need to be able to set icons for the JTree individual nodes. For example, I have a JTree and I need the nodes to have custom icons that help represent what they are.

- (wrench icon) Settings
- (bug icon) Debug
- (smiley face icon) Fun Stuff

...

And so on. I have tried several sources and got one somewhat working, but it messed up the tree events so, no cigar. Thanks in advance.

As someone requested:

```
class Country {
    private String name;
    private String flagIcon;

    Country(String name, String flagIcon) {
        this.name = name;
        this.flagIcon = flagIcon;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFlagIcon() {
        return flagIcon;
    }

    public void setFlagIcon(String flagIcon) {
        this.flagIcon = flagIcon;
    }
}

class CountryTreeCellRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {
    private JLabel label;

    CountryTreeCellRenderer() {
        label = new JLabel();
    }

    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        Object o = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
        if (o instanceof Country) {
            Country country = (Country) o;
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(country.getFlagIcon()));
            label.setText(country.getName());
        } else {
            label.setIcon(null);
            label.setText("" + value);
        }
        return label;
    }
}
```

Then where it's initialized:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Countries");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode asia = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("General");
    Country[] countries = new Country[]{
            new Country("Properties", "src/biz/jabaar/lotus/sf/icons/page_white_edit.png"),
            new Country("Network", "src/biz/jabaar/lotus/sf/icons/drive_network.png"),
    };

    for (Country country : countries) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(country);
        asia.add(node);
    }
```

And this works, it's just I don't want the sub-roots to show, just the nodes. Also, this code makes it so that the item won't highlight when you click it.

Comment: _and got one somewhat working_...great, please post and describe the issue you are having

Comment: Not really necessary as it's not what I need anyways but it's posted.

Comment: What do you mean by sub-roots?

Comment: Uhm, I don't know the proper name for them, they are the things that open and close so you can see the nodes in them. Sorry.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (of your closest attempt).

Comment: I did, it's up there in the OP. I need some help, not random comments. Thanks anyways.

Comment: And we could do with more effort, try look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096725/jtree-set-custom-open-closed-icons-for-individual-groups/14098574#14098574) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display)

Comment: -1 for insisting to not provide the necessary information to make reasonable answers possible

Comment: What? Did you even see the OP? What else do I need to provide? I identified the issue, posted code, explained what I need. How in the world is that not sufficient? And if you needed more just say so, because from what everyone has said, that is enough.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want the sub-roots to show, just the nodes.

Your implementation of `getTreeCellRendererComponent()` should see a properly conditioned `boolean leaf` parameter that you can use as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8351850/230513).

```
if (o instanceof Country && leaf) { ... }
```