# Adding custom property to JTree and also print it

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I'm trying to implement a `FP-Tree`. So I have used a `JTree`. I have created my tree successfully. But I need to add two custom properties to my nodes, 'Label' and 'LabelCount'

And I also need to print it in the tree. Is that possible?

Comment: The DefaultMutableTreeNode takes a "user object" (which it uses as the default value for rendering the node). Your best bet would be to create a simple Property object and applying to each node

Answer (score 1):

Use DefaultMutableTreeNode as nodes and add a user object to that, than add your own implementation of TreeCellRenderer to the tree (setTreecellRenderer(...)
In your TreeCellRenderer implement the getTreeCellRendererComponent method.

```
Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree,
                                 Object value,
                                 boolean selected,
                                 boolean expanded,
                                 boolean leaf,
                                 int row,
                                 boolean hasFocus)
```

The Object value argument will be your DefaultMutableTreeNode which contains your user object.

You can just return a JLabel (or any other Component) that contains the text you want.

For performance reasons you can reuse your JLabel, no need to create a new one every time the method is called.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8351850/230513). You might cite the printing tutorial.