# Calling JTree from another class

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jmenuitem

I'm having trouble making a `JMenuItem` in one class pull up a `JTree` from another class that would act as a `Help` menu for a program I'm making. The main problem I'm having is calling the `JTree` from the one class through an `ActionListener` in the `JMenuItem`'s class.

Here's the code from the JMenuItem's class that I'm talking about:

```
/*pulls up help menu*/
JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("Help Menu");
myMenu.add(item1);
item1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
     **if(item1.isEnabled()){
        sjt = new SampleJTree();
     }**
 }
});
```

As I stated before, I'm not sure how to bring a JTree via the bold section (i.e. I don't know what to put in the if statement check).  Any direction to the solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: You may need to provide quite a bit more information to make this question answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial article [*How to Use Trees*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) includes [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#eg) that show how to construct a `JTree` and make it visible. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8210759/230513) shows how to search a tree for a matching string and make the corresponding node visible.

Addendum: For reference, [*How to Use Actions*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) offers a useful way to encapsulate the `ActionListener`.