# How to Collapse and Expand in JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

```
root
  A         //sub node
    A1     //sub node
      A11     // leaf node
    A2     // sub node
  B
    B1
    B2
  C
```

is there way to collapse/expand the sub nodes in dynamically. 
i tried this way

```
 tree.collapsePath(PreselectedPath);
 tree.expandPath(currentSelectedPath); 
 or 
 tree.expandRow(currentIndex);
 tree.collapseRow(preIndex);
```

it will works on first level node only apart from that it wont work.
 so is there any way to collapse/expand accordingly..?

Comment: Walk through all the nodes and collapse each one, be warned, this can be time consuming

Comment: Thanks for your replay.  i found solution in this blog :   http://orinanobworld.blogspot.in/2013/03/auto-collapsing-tree-in-java.html

Comment: Refer : Auto Collapse/Expand for Tree  http://orinanobworld.blogspot.in/2013/03/auto-collapsing-tree-in-java.html

Comment: Just beware, we were trying things like this about found when you had quite a few nodes (hundreds), this process took quite some time (minutes)

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8210630/230513).