# JTree model.nodechanged(Node) loses data

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtree

I am testing some code with `JTree`, and I noticed that `model.reload()` gives different output than `model.nodeChanged(currentNode)`. The correct output is obtained from `model.reload()`. Here are my two outputs for the same code:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
public class test {

    private JFrame frame;
    JTree tree;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root;
    DefaultTreeModel model;
    private Map<String, DefaultMutableTreeNode> treeMap;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test t = new test();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 5);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        t.add_new_folder("Data", "trial 0");
        t.add_new_folder("Data/trial 0", "trial 1");
        t.add_new_folder("Data/trial 0/trial 1", "trial 2");
        t.add_new_folder("Data", "trial 1");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 5);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        t.add_new_folder("Data/trial 1", "trial 2");
        t.add_new_folder("Data", "trial 2");
    }

    public test() {
        frame = new JFrame("using reload");
        tree = new JTree();
        root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Data");
        model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        tree.setModel(model);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tree, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        treeMap = new HashMap<>();
        treeMap.put("Data", root);
    }

    public void add_new_folder(String path, String name) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode = treeMap.get(path);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(name);
        currentNode.add(childNode);
        treeMap.put(path + "/" + name, childNode);
        model.reload();
        //model.nodeChanged(currentNode);
    }
}
```

I need also to use `model.nodeChanged()` as it keeps expanded paths the same unlike `model.reload`. Any explanation and how to fix?

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! IDEs usually have a [shortcut for formatting code](https://www.google.com.au/?ion=1&espv=2#q=eclipse%20format%20code)..

Comment: i did the auto format but didnt help

Comment: Well, good luck with it. Life's too short to deal with unfromatted code.

Comment: ! i don`t understand your point !

Comment: Your unformatted code is hard to read, but it is clearly wrong: _don't_ sleep on the [*Initial Thread*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html);  _do_ see [*Concurrency in Swing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: oh ok thanks for the note. any idea why this problem facing me with the JTree??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea why this problem facing me with the `Tree`?

As shown below, when correctly [synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), the results are the same. As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28952936/230513), you can control visibility using `expandRow()` and `scrollPathToVisible()`. Using `Thread.sleep()` will simply block the thread on which it is called. Because Swing is [single-threaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7158505/230513), the results are unpredictable. Instead use [`java.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) or [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) as needed.

> Try to put some sleep between adding nodes and expand any path and in the continue code the problem will appear as stated in my question.

For the reasons [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7158505/230513), results using `Thread.sleep()` are not reliable. Using `java.swing.Timer` reveals the problem: `nodeChanged()` reflects changes to the node itself. Because you've changed the children of the node, invoke `nodeStructureChanged()` instead.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

public class Test {

    private final JFrame frame;
    private final JTree tree;
    private final DefaultMutableTreeNode root;
    private final DefaultTreeModel model;
    private final Map<String, DefaultMutableTreeNode> treeMap;
    private final boolean reload;
    private int index;
    private final String[] folders = {
        "Data", "trial 0",
        "Data/trial 0", "trial 1",
        "Data/trial 0/trial 1", "trial 2",
        "Data", "trial 1",
        "Data/trial 1", "trial 2",
        "Data", "trial 2"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Test(true);
            new Test(false);
        });
    }

    public Test(boolean reload) {
        this.reload = reload;
        frame = new JFrame(String.valueOf(reload));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        treeMap = new HashMap<>();
        root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Data");
        model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        tree = new JTree(model);
        treeMap.put("Data", root);
        frame.add(tree, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Timer t = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (index < folders.length) {
                    addNewFolder(folders[index++], folders[index++]);
                    for (int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
                        tree.expandRow(i);
                    }
                    frame.pack();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    private void addNewFolder(String path, String name) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode = treeMap.get(path);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(name);
        currentNode.add(childNode);
        treeMap.put(path + "/" + name, childNode);
        if (reload) {
            model.reload();
        } else {
            model.nodeStructureChanged(currentNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i got the same results when its all done without getting the chance of expanding any path.to be more specific i only got this difference when i expand any path while thread in a sleep.

Comment: try to put some sleep between adding nodes and expand any path and in the continue code the problem will appear as stated in my question

Comment: I've elaborated above.